# New Azure Portal Blade View UI Control

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, responsive-design

The new Azure Portal introduced a new control UI that is called "Blade Panel" or "Blade View" I think.  It has the UI pattern of master details that keeps getting deeper and where the details display to the rights of the parent content.  There is a **BladeView** control in the UWP Community Tool Kit (see ), but **I wonder if there are any open source or third party javascript/HTML5 renditions out there?**  **If so, can someone elaborate on which are the best?**

Comment: I'm interested in creating something like this for a web application

Comment: would really love to see this also!

Comment: Anyone got a chance to meet such a component?

Comment: I'm not aware of any to date, but would hope that VuetifyJS creates one.